# Steps to Back-up Entire Website for Transfer

Tags: web, backup, restore, transfer

I hope I am not duplicating/putting this question in the wrong area, if so, please move-it or redirect me to the post I have duplicated.  Thanks in advance.

I am wanting to know the steps to backing up an entire website when moving from one host to another.  After a bit a research, I have found the following:

```
1. Backup actual website files (from public_html htdocs, or whatever your main root folder is called.

2. Backup database using phpmyadmin's export as sql and save-as file feature.
```

My question is, is there anything else I should back-up / make note of previous to transferring my site?  Anything else I should be aware of?  Any other files/etc. (required or not) that may cause issues during the process?